# Create and save in component , from different controller to diffrent model.non-object error

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4

TagController

```
public function view($id = null) {
    if ($this->request->data != null) {
        $this->Common->replyarticleAdd($this);
    }
}
```

CommonComponent
/*

```
App::uses('Link', 'Model');
App::uses('User', 'Model');
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');*/
```

I think , I should write it and it loads model but not effect.

```
ClassRegistry::init('Article');
App::uses('Article', 'Model');
ClassRegistry::init('Article');
App::uses('Article', 'Model');

class CommonComponent extends Component {
    var $uses = array('Article');
    public function replyarticleAdd($that = null) { // $this error can not re-assign.

        debug($that->request->params['pass'][0]);
        if ($that->request->params['pass'][0] != null) {
            $this->Article->create(); // that is no effect
```

Error `Call to a member function create() on a non-object`

File: G:\pleiades\xampp\htdocs\cakephp\app\Controller\Component\CommonComponent.php 
`Line: 13 = $this->Article->create();`

In controller create is ok but in component it cant. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the component, try to work with the models this way:

```
App::uses('Article', 'Model');
$Article = new Article();
$Article->create();
```

Components do not have the `$uses` property, like controllers.

You can also use:

```
$Article = ClassRegistry::init('Article');
$Article->create();
```